# Antibiotic resistance of Staphylococcus epidermidis and S. warneri

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, antibiotics

I am looking for information regarding the antibiotic resistance of *S. epidermidis* and *S. warneri*, specifically against penicillin, ampicillin and tetracycline but to no avail. Are there any good websites with databases where this information is shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some studies concerning the antibiotic resistance of *Staphylococcus epidermidis* and *Staphylococcus warneri*:

[Antibiotic resistance patterns of coagulase-negative staphylococcus strains isolated from blood cultures of septicemic patients in Turkey - Koksal, Yasar & Samasti [2009]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0944501307000560)

The abstract of the study above reads as follows:

> The aim of this study is to determine antibiotic resistance patterns
>   and slime production characteristics of coagulase-negative
>   Staphylococci (CoNS) caused nosocomial bacteremia. A total of 200 CoNS
>   strains were isolated from blood samples of patients with true
>   bacteremia who were hospitalized in intensive care units and in other
>   departments of Istanbul University Cerrahpasa Medical Hospital between
>   1999 and 2006. Among 200 CoNS isolates, Staphylococcus epidermidis was
>   the most prevalent species (87) followed by Staphylococcus
>   haemolyticus (23), Staphylococcus hominis (19), Staphylococcus
>   lugdunensis (18), Staphylococcus capitis (15), Staphylococcus xylosus
>   (10), **Staphylococcus warneri** (8), Staphylococcus saprophyticus (5),
>   Staphylococcus lentus (5), Staphylococcus simulans (4), Staphylococcus
>   chromogenes (3), Staphylococcus cohnii (1), Staphylococcus schleiferi
>   (1), and Staphylococcus auricularis (1). Resistance to methicillin was
>   detected in 67.5% of CoNS isolates. Methicillin-resistant CoNS strains
>   were determined to be more resistant to antibiotics than
>   methicillin-susceptible CoNS strains. Resistance rates of
>   methicillin-resistant and methicillin-susceptible CoNS strains to the
>   antibacterial agents, respectively, were as follows: gentamicin 90%
>   and 17%, erythromycin 80% and 37%, clindamycin 72% and 18%,
>   trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole 68% and 38%, ciprofloxacin 67% and 23%,
>   **tetracycline 60%** and 45%, chloramphenicol 56% and 13% and fusidic acid
>   25% and 15%. None of the strains were resistant to vancomycin and
>   teicoplanin. Slime production was detected in 86 of 200 CoNS strains.
>   Resistance to methicillin was found in 81% of slime-positive and in
>   57% of slime-negative strains. Our results indicated that there is a
>   high level of resistance to widely used agents in causative
>   methicillin-resistant CoNS strains. However fusidic acid has the
>   smallest resistance ratio, with the exception of glycopeptides.
>   Additionally, most **S. epidermidis** strains were slime-positive, with
>   statistically significant (p<0.001) association between methicillin
>   resistance and slime production.

The other two studies contain information on the aforementioned strains with regards to penicillin susceptibility.

[Antibiotic-resistant Staphylococcus epidermidis in patients undergoing cardiac surgery - Archer & Tenenbaum [1980]](http://aac.asm.org/content/17/2/269.full.pdf+html)

[Clinical significance of Staphylococcus warneri bacteremia - Kamath, Singer & Isenberg [1992]](http://jcm.asm.org/content/30/2/261.full.pdf+html)

In addition, I would recommend to acquaint yourself with [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/) for these kind of questions. It normally makes for a good starting point.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (don't just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.

Comment: Fair point @Chris. I will amend my answer at the earliest convenience. I may have been lead astray/tempted by O.kth question for a website / database. However, I agree with what you say in your comment.